# Finding and fixing the missing div tags - WordPress custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I am having a problem with the page http://www.believeinstjohn.com/store/

What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is moving the sidebar to its proper place (right sidebar column). It is showing three missing `</div>`tags, it is a WordPress site and the page is using a custom template. I cannot figure out where the missing tags are. The template is pulling resources from the rest of the site, and the other pages are just fine. Two of the divs (container & container-2) are located in the header.php, but closing them out there messes up the whole site. I must have missed something in the template, but cannot see it. Here is the PHP for the template

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Products
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Adventure_Journal
 */
$themeOpts = get_option('ctx-adventurejournal-options');
get_header();
?>

        <div class="content" <?php ctx_aj_getlayout(); ?>>
            <div id="col-main" style="<?php echo ctx_aj_customwidth('content'); ?>">
              <div id="main-content" <?php //ctx_aj_crinkled_paper(); ?>>

    <?php 
    global $wp_query, $post;
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $tax = $wp_query->query_vars['product-category'];
    query_posts( array ('post_type' => 'products', 'paged' => $paged, 'product-category' => $tax ) );
    $loop_counter = 1;
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li class="product <?php if ( $loop_counter == 2 ) { echo "product-last"; } ?>">
            <div class="product_wrap">
                <?php 
                $title = get_the_title().' ';
                $chars_title = strlen($title);
                $title = substr($title,0,28);
                $title = substr($title,0,strrpos($title,' '));
                if ($chars_title > 28) { $title = $title."..."; } 

                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                if (strlen($excerpt) > 150) {
                $excerpt = substr($excerpt,0,strpos($excerpt,' ',80)); } ;
                $excerpt = $excerpt.' ...';

                if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" class="product-thumb" title="'. the_title_attribute('echo=0') .'">';
                    the_post_thumbnail( 'Product Thumb', array('title'=>$post_title) );
                    echo  '</a>';
                }
                ?>
                <h3 class="entry-title product-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h3>
                <div class="product_content">
                    <?php echo apply_filters('the_excerpt',$excerpt); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php if ( $loop_counter == 2 ) {
            $loop_counter = 1;
            echo '<li class="clear"></li>';
        } else {
            $loop_counter++;
        } ?>
     <?php endwhile; else: endif;  ?>
 <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php get_sidebar('store'); ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you close the following tags ?

```
<div class="content" <?php ctx_aj_getlayout(); ?>>
<div id="col-main" style="<?php echo ctx_aj_customwidth('content'); ?>">
<div id="main-content" <?php //ctx_aj_crinkled_paper(); ?>>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make sure that I indented far enough - here: `   <?php get_sidebar('store'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: If you only use 2x </div> then you are stil missing a closing div tag.

Comment: Thank you, Bob - you pointed me in the right direction. It wasn't a matter of them being closed, but WHERE they were closed.  Got that part straightened out.